# is it necessary or good practice to sanitize the parameters for all three devise actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, model-view-controller, devise

The Devise [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) state that there are three actions that allow parameters to be passed on down to the model: :sign_up, :sign_in, and :account_update. The following example (based off their doc) suggests that I use a before filter.

```
protected 

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :username, :website, :invitation_code])
end
```

They don't explicitly state that it's a good idea to also sanitize parameters for the other two actions, or if it's a good idea to sanitize other (non-Devise) model params. This is where I'm confused. Should I add to the above code so that it's like this?

```
protected 

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :username, :website, :invitation_code])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:email, :username, :password])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:email, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :password_confirmation, :website])
end
```

Also, how do I know that the parameters are being converted to a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sanitize parameters that are never used. Presumably in your login (`:sign_in` in devise) you're only using `username` and `password` so there is no need to sanitize any extra parameters there.

If the user can update his/her `first_name`, `website` and so on in your edit form you're gonna need that however for the `:account_update` parameters.

Comment: That makes sense. So I'll need a sanitizing method for each action. Thanks!